# Redux actions to reducers not showing in devtools state

Tags: redux

I'd managed to get some of my earlier functions state in devtools as below:

Reducers function in DevTools

But when I tried to query some of the events in my interactions, the functions state werent able to display it. Below are my codes and settings, basically the flow is interactions > actions > reducers

interaction code:

```
export const loadAllOrders = async (exchange, dispatch) => {
    // Fetch cancelled orders with the "Cancel" event stream    
    const fromBlock = 0;
    const toBlock = "latest";
    const cancelFilter = exchange.filters.CancelOrder();
    const cancelStream = await exchange.queryFilter(cancelFilter, fromBlock, toBlock);
    console.log(cancelStream)
    // Format cancelled orders
    const cancelledOrders = cancelStream.map((event) => event.args);
    // Add cancelled orders to the redux store
    dispatch(cancelledOrdersLoaded(cancelledOrders));
}
```

from my actions:

```
export const cancelledOrdersLoaded = (cancelledOrders) => {
    return {
        type: 'CANCELLED_ORDERS_LOADED',
        payload:cancelledOrders
    }
}
```

from my reducers:

```
export const exchange = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'EXCHANGE_LOADED':
            return { ...state, loaded:true, contract: action.payload }
        case 'CANCELLED_ORDERS_LOADED':
            return { ...state, cancelledOrders: action.payload }
        default:
          return state

}
```

my configureStore

```
// For redux dev tools
const devTools = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  compose(applyMiddleware(thunk),devTools)
)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with redux for quite some time now, but from a quick look at some of my older repos, it seems like you didn't set up your store correctly.

This is what I have there,

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore, compose, combineReducers } from "redux"
import thunk from "redux-thunk"

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  reducers...
})

export const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk)))
```

Comment: I've configured as below but still return the same result                                    
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import rootReducer from "./reducers";
import thunk from  "redux-thunk";


// For redux dev tools
const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

const store = createStore( rootReducer, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk)))
  

export default store;

Comment: @0xhaz This might help you, [Troubleshooting Redux-devtools](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/blob/master/docs/Troubleshooting.md)

Comment: Thanks but still got the same results. I've suspect that I'd messed up my syntax on reducers since there is no issue with my other calls. Trying to research on redux now